# Who was the oldest martyr of Karbala?

Tags: hussain, martyr, battle-of-karbala

As probably many of you are aware, at the time of Imam Hussain (a.s.) there was a tragedy event which was/is famous as "Battle-of-Karbala". It is as follow:

- [www.al-islam.org/the-tragedy-of-karbala](http://www.al-islam.org/the-tragedy-of-karbala-collection-of-texts)

But the question which I am looking for, is that who the name of the oldest person of Battle-of-Karbala (as the soldier of Imam Hussain (a.s.)) was who was martyred during the battle.

Answer (score 2):

> Who is the name of the oldest martyr of Karbala (کربلا)?

He is:

**Habib ibn Mazaaher /  (حبیب بن مظاهر)**

More info. about him:

```
(http://en.wikishia.net/view/Habib_b._Muzahir)
```

---

References:

- [www.wikiporsesh.ir](http://www.wikiporsesh.ir/%D8%A8%D8%B2%D8%B1%DA%AF%E2%80%8C%D8%AA%D8%B1%DB%8C%D9%86_%D9%88_%DA%A9%D9%88%D8%AC%DA%A9%E2%80%8C%D8%AA%D8%B1%DB%8C%D9%86_%D8%B4%D9%87%DB%8C%D8%AF_%DA%A9%D8%B1%D8%A8%D9%84%D8%A7)
- [www.ashoora.ir](http://www.ashoora.ir/2012-11-16-16-24-30/%D8%A7%D8%B5%D8%AD%D8%A7%D8%A8-%D8%A7%D9%85%D8%A7%D9%85/3211-%D9%85%D8%B3%D9%86-%D8%AA%D8%B1%D9%8A%D9%86-%D9%88-%D9%83%D9%88%DA%86%D9%83%D8%AA%D8%B1%D9%8A%D9%86-%D8%B4%D9%87%D9%8A%D8%AF-%D9%83%D8%B1%D8%A8%D9%84%D8%A7-%D8%B1%D8%A7-%D9%85%D8%B9%D8%B1%D9%81%D9%8A-%D9%83%D9%86%D9%8A%D8%AF%D8%9F.html)